# Typescript npm library can't export Redux store please advice

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, notistack

I use the [Notistack](https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack) library and [forked](https://codesandbox.io/s/notistack-test-3kwyv?file=/src/index.js) it and then using VSCode to try to add a Redux store in the library that I want to expose to Apps.

I'm not so good with Typescript. I have some trouble hehe.

What I want to do is that when the app is using Notistack to show a snack message. I want to use Redux to update the message in real time, like a file up/download progress showing on the snack. It's here  Notistack new Redux store(that i create here) come into play. I want Notistack to expose the Redux store to the app so the app can send redux `dispatch` into to Notistack Redux Store. and showing  `dispatched` message in the Notistack [SnackbarItem.tsx](https://codesandbox.io/s/notistack-test-3kwyv?file=/src/SnackbarItem/SnackbarItem.tsx)
(hope you understand)

When I compile in VSCode I get this error in my app:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/redux/root-reducer.js
Attempted import error: 'notistack' does not contain a default export (imported as 'NotisReducer').
```

My root-reducer in the App look like this:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import NotisReducer from 'notistack';
import snackReducer from './snackbar/snack.reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    snack: snackReducer,
    NotisReducer,
});
export default rootReducer;
```

As you see I import Notistack's `NotisReducer` and I think I have implemented that.

**(I have used [NPM link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-link) to add locally forked Notistack library into my app)**

Now it looks like this here is Notistack's [indext.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/notistack-test-3kwyv?file=/src/index.js) file where I expose Redux [store](https://codesandbox.io/s/notistack-test-3kwyv?file=/src/Redux/store.js) as `NotisReducer`:

[image]

What I did in Notistack was I added a to [index.d.ts](https://codesandbox.io/s/notistack-test-3kwyv?file=/src/index.d.ts):

I define the type `store` like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { SnackbarClassKey } from '@material-ui/core/Snackbar';
import { ClickAwayListenerProps } from '@material-ui/core/ClickAwayListener';
import { TransitionProps } from '@material-ui/core/transitions/transition';
import { StandardProps } from '@material-ui/core';
import store from './Redux/store'; // MY STORE
...
...
export type store = store; // EXPORT IT
```

I'm not sure if this is correct as I could not set breakpoint in  npm linked Notistack. Maybe it's to many problem now that must be fixed first.

In the file
[SnackbarProvider.tsx](https://codesandbox.io/s/notistack-test-3kwyv?file=/src/SnackbarProvider.tsx)
I did like this, importing the `store` type from [index.d.ts](https://codesandbox.io/s/notistack-test-3kwyv?file=/src/index.d.ts)):

```
import {
  SnackbarProviderProps,
  SnackbarKey,
  SnackbarMessage,
  OptionsObject,
  RequiredBy,
  ProviderContext,
  TransitionHandlerProps,
  store, //  STORE
} from ".";
import createChainedFunction from "./utils/createChainedFunction";

export { store }; // EXPOSING IT
```

In the file
[NotisReducer.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/notistack-test-3kwyv?file=/src/NotisReducer.js)
I import the `store` to be sent to  [indext.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/notistack-test-3kwyv?file=/src/index.js) above

[image]

But as you saw above I get compiler error store is not exported.

```
Attempted import error: 'notistack' does not contain a default ex (imported as 'NotisReducer').
```

please advice :))